# Format of Metal compiled metallib shader file?

Tags: shader, metal

For runtime-generated shader code, I'm interested in exploring whether it's possible to auto-generate compiled *Metal Shader Language (MSL)* code directly (as found in a `.metallib` file, and as used with the `newLibraryWithData:error:` method), instead of auto-generating human-readable MSL source code (as used with the `newLibraryWithSource:options:error:` method).

Rationale for this are two-fold:

1. Depending on the compiled-code format, it may be simpler and cleaner for a program to auto-generate compiled shader code, rather than messing around with the human-readable format.
2. Removing the shader compile stage would speed-up the creation of runtime-generated shaders.

Is documentation available for the format of compiled MSL code, as found in a `.metallib` file? And is the compiled format GPU-specific, or does it exist as an intermediate-language format that is taken to the GPU-level during a final compilation stage within the `newLibraryWithData:error:` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of `metallib` files is not publicly documented. Library files essentially contain metadata and compiled shader code in an LLVM-derived intermediate language, which is device-agnostic. There is a second, back-end compilation step that transforms this intermediate language into the final machine code. It is not possible to generate intermediate code directly, but if this is a feature you want, you should file an enhancement request bug with Apple.

Comment: Thanks. What is your source for understanding the internal structure (eg- that it's intermediate language plus meta, etc)?

Comment: format is somewhat documented here: https://github.com/gfx-rs/naga/wiki/Metallib-file-format